# Selection - ShapeRange and chart issue

Tags: vba, excel

I've found a problem with obtaining name properties from my hand made selection.

I use very simple code to get selected shapes names:

```
Selection.ShapeRange(i).Name
```

Everything works fine and I get names of autoshapes, smartarts, charts.
The problem shows up when I have only one object selected and the object is a chart. I try to execute my code (or try any method else for example some simple: top, left and other methods) and I am getting such error:

```
Run-time error "438":

Object doesn't support this propert or method
```

I don't understand it. Is the possible list of methods different for charts when they are selected alone than when selected with other charts/shapes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
If TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Then
    Debug.Print ActiveChart.Parent.Name
Else
    Debug.Print Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
End If
```

I am assuming that a `Shape` is selected when you run this code.

**Edit**

Or you can use `Selection.Parent.Parent.Name` instead of `ActiveChart.Parent.Name`

In school, while learning Geometry, I learned that a `Square` can be a `Rectangle` but a `Rectangle` can not be called a `Square`. Both are Geometric shapes yet they have different properties. Similarly, a rectangular shape and a chart are shapes but it is **not** necessary that they will share the same properties. Another example would be a `Range` is an `Object` but so is a `Shape`. But then you cannot weigh them in the same scale. They have to be addressed as separate objects

The above code can be further narrowed down to

```
Select Case TypeName(Selection)
    Case "ChartArea": Debug.Print Selection.Parent.Parent.Name
    Case "Range": Debug.Print Selection.Address
    Case Else: Debug.Print Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name
End Select
```

Comment: +1 seen that someone has provided an answer while I was doing mine haha

Comment: plus one yourself... :) Actually, I had seen your comment under OP's question. I felt that comment was incorrect(prob that is why you deleted it?) and hence I thought, I'll answer the question :)

Comment: yeah the comment was misworded and incorrect. I was thinking something else but couldn't make a sentence out of my train of thoughts :P fridays im like that :P

Comment: After 6 PM, I will be in that state ;)

Comment: Very nice idea, I forgot about such a nice feature as TypeName function. Now I came up with some idea if I have a multiple selection of many objects, I can do **Selection.Count** and then **Selection.Item(i)** to loop through my objects instead of **shaperange** method, and with **TypeName()** function assess what kind of object I am dealing with thus having different part of code for different object types. Thanks for bringing great idea :)